# How to port forward?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I want to make a few servers (mostly Minecraft) to play with my friends without using Hamachi or Tunngle and i found out about port forwarding.
I've tried a couple of tutorials online but didn't seem to get it done.

I have a weird router setup:
ISP's Optical Fibre -> Main Router -> Router1 & Router2
We have 3 houses, one is the office and the other 2 are duplex. The office has the Main Router and the optical fibre and the other houses have each their own router: Router 1 respectively Router 2.

I'm using Router 1 via Ethernet and after  alot of YouTube and Google i can't seem to make the port open. It is open in the router's admin page and is set up correctly but i still can't host a server.

Tried OpenPortCheckTool with the server open but it says that the port is closed.

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, you've set the port forwarding in the main router?

Comment: You will have to port forward through all of the routers on the path from the computer to the Internet.  Also, keep in mind some ISPs block connections to some ports: http://customer.xfinity.com/help-and-support/internet/list-of-blocked-ports/

Comment: No. I only port forwarded the router i'm using (Router 1).
And how can i port forward through each router ?
The static IP address is only on my router (Router 1).

Comment: See @Steven 's comment. You need to do it on all, or the traffic will be blocked on its way, and thus not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're behind "Router1", and it's behind "Main Router", then you need to forward the ports in Main Router to Router1, and then forward the ports from Router1 to your servers.

Comment: So for example Minecraft: port 25565. I would get Router 1's IP and the Minecraft port and set those in Main Router admin page ?

Comment: Yup.  You'll want to use the IP address of Router1 that the Main Router see it as (e.g.: the WAN IP of Router1)

Comment: OK. So i got Router1's WAN IP and port forwarded it in Main Router then port forwarded my PC's STATIC IP and the same port to Router1.
Tested with open port check tool and the port seemed to be open. Now i need to test with a friend. What IP should i give it to him ?

Comment: The WAN IP of Main Router, or whatever appears as your public IP on the Internet, [Google "What is my IP"](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip) and it'll tell you.